# Building an index of items from an iterable-of-tuples

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

Is there a more conventional / standard / easy-to-read way of building an index of tuples from an iterable than this:

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
def build_index(itable_tup):
    """
    Return an index for an iterable container of tuples, all the same length.
    The last element in each tuple is treated as the payload value
    that is to be indexed, and the preceeding elements as a hierarchy
    of indices by which it is to be indexed.
    The index itself is a nested default-dictionary with len(tup)
    levels of nesting, containing a list at the innermost level
    to hold the payload.
    >>> idx = build_index((('a','b', 1), ('a','c', 2)))
    >>> import json
    >>> print(json.dumps(idx, sort_keys=True))
    {"a": {"b": [1], "c": [2]}}
    This function is a bit of an exercise in making use of the
    functional programming capabilities that come with Python,
    so the  implementation is a little more terse and opaque
    than it might otherwise be...
    For each tuple in iter_tup, we construct a slot in the index
    using the lazy initialisation capability that is provided by
    the collections.defaultdict class. All but the last element
    in the tuple are used for indexing. The last element is the
    payload which gets added to the inner list after the structure
    has been initialised. The basic capability is provided by
    the nested defaultdict data structure returned from the idx_ctor
    function, which in turn is built with the aid of the higher
    order lambda function (_partial(_dedict, ctor)).
    All this is plugged together using calls to functools.reduce,
    which is used to construct the custom index data structure; to
    add each tuple to the index, as well as to iterate over the
    input.
    """
    _dedict   = collections.defaultdict
    _chain    = itertools.chain
    _repeat   = itertools.repeat
    _reduce   = functools.reduce
    _partial  = functools.partial
    _getitem  = operator.getitem

    # Peek ahead to determine the tuple length (& reconstitute the iterator).
    iter_tup  = iter(itable_tup)
    try:
        first_tup = iter_tup.__next__()
    except StopIteration:
        return {}
    idx_depth = len(first_tup) - 1
    iter_all  = _chain([first_tup], iter_tup)

    # Create a constructor for a custom index data structure.
    idx_ctor = _reduce(lambda ctor, _: _partial(_dedict, ctor),
                       _repeat(None, idx_depth), list)

    # This function adds a sigle tuple to the custom index data structure.
    def _add_tup_to_idx(idx, tup):
        """
        Add a sigle tuple to the custom index data structure.
        """
        _reduce(_getitem, tup[:-1], idx).append(tup[-1])
        return idx

    # This iterates over all tuples adding each to the index in turn.
    return _reduce(_add_tup_to_idx, iter_all, idx_ctor())
```

Comment: I have trouble testing `TypeError: build_index() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)` when running `build_index((('a','b', 1), ('a','c', 2)), 3)`

Comment: The doctest should have read: - idx = build_index((('a','b', 1), ('a','c', 2)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use make variables scoped to a function 'private'.
They're 'protected' so please, just remove the `_` from them.

If we look at your `next` block.
You use `iter_tup.__next__()`.
Don't.
Use `next`!
If you see `__{name}__` then you should *always* check if there is a better way.
And so I'd use:

```
first = next(iterator, None)
if first is None:
    return {}
```

The next block to get the length and to rebuild the iterator is fine.

The `reduce` is fine, I dislike how static it is.
And so if I were to write this function I'd change it.
But it's fine.

I'd change `_add_tup_to_idx` to just a plain for loop.
Sure it means you mutate something, oh well.
It's much easier to read and understand.
I'd change it to:

```
dictionary = idx_ctor()
for tup in iter_all:
    reduce(_getitem, tup[:-1], dictionary).append(tup[-1])
return dictionary
```

Finally I'll go over a few more 'high-level' things. It's much easier to read if you use good variable names.
Take for example:

```
def build_index(iterator):
    iterator = iter(iterator)
    first = next(iterator)
    if first is None:
        return {}
    depth = len(first) - 1
    iterator = chain([first], iterator)

    ddict = reduce(lambda d, _: partial(defaultdict, d),
                   repeat(None, depth),
                   list)
    dictionary = ddict()
    for item in iterator:
        reduce(getitem, item[:-1], dictionary).append(item[-1])
    return dictionary
```

Now you seem to put emphasis on it being a hash-tree.
But what do you get if you do:

```
build_index((('a',), ('b',), ('c',)))
```

Is it a dictionary, or is it a list?
Now what do you get if you enter these:

```
build_index((('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd')))
build_index(())
```

Yes the they return different types.
The above two are dictionary's, and the first is a list.
That is a massive edge case.

I think the design should be based around an infinite default dict.
And for it to *always* return a dict.
And so you could use the following recursive function:

```
def ddict():
    return defaultdict(ddict)
```

Now we just have to change your for loop.
If we slice the string into two at the second to last position,
and remove the item from the list if the second is empty:

```
dictionary = ddict()
for head, tail in ((i[:-2], i[-2:]) for i in iterable):
    if not tail:
        continue
```

Now before you say, that's not functional!
Yeah it's half functional, well the comprehension is.
It's easier to read this way, as if Python were a functional based language it'd be more like:

```
iterable
    .map(i => (i[:-2], i[-2:]))
    .filter(i => i[1])
```

Now we could do that, but it'd be icky, take:

```
(i for i in ((i[:-2], i[-2:]) for i in iterable) if i[0])
filter(lambda i: i[0], map(lambda i: (i[:-2], i[-2:]), iterable))
```

And so they all are the same, so just go for the most readable.

For the last bit, we will do what you were doing before.
But with two changes.
To allow for `tail` to have a length of one, we need to use `extend` rather than `append`.
and to get a list you'll have to use `setdefault` with a list.

This gives a quite functional function:

```
def build_index(iterable):
    def ddict():
        return defaultdict(ddict)
    dictionary = ddict()
    for head, tail in ((i[:-2], i[-2:]) for i in iterable):
        if not tail:
            continue
        (reduce(getitem, head, dictionary)
            .setdefault(tail[0], [])
            .extend(tail[1:]))
    return dictionary
```

You can also change `getitem` to a function that uses `setdefault` to remove the need for `defaultdict` and `getitem`.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to use comments for "Thanks" messages -- but I feel that I really should say how impressed I am by how thoughtful and detailed this review is. I'll have to try to digest it in more detail, but I can't see anything that I object to or disagree with as yet.

Comment: @WilliamPayne No problem, if you do find anything that you disagree with then just ping me! I know it's not a functional as you may want, and that's what I feel like every now and then, but readability trumps purity imho.